# Image URL appears in a wrong place in WordPress shortcode output

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to make a shortcode for displaying logged in user avatar from buddypress

```
// user avtar
function user_avatar() {
    $user_avatar_url = bp_loggedin_user_avatar('type=full&html=false'); 
    $user_image = '<img src="' . $user_avatar_url  . '"/>';
    return $user_image;
}
add_shortcode('avatar', 'user_avatar');
```

but when I try to insert shortcode [avatar], the HTML output looks like this:

```
http://localhost/.../images/bp_default_avatar.jpg <img src=""></img>
```

Somehow image url/src appears before 'img' tag?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, just the wrong formatted output

Comment: try `echo` instead of `return`

Comment: tried that already, the same result

Comment: try this `$user_image = "<img src=\"".$user_avatar_url."\"/>";`

Comment: again, the same result

Comment: try changing the function name, maybe there is another function it is referencing

Comment: :) yeah I was thinking the same like 20 minutes ago, no there's no function name conflicts

Comment: btw 
`var_dump ($user_image);`
gives this info:
string '<img src=""/>' (length=13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was the buddypress issue, I changed a few things and now it's working

```
// user avtar
function user_avatar() {
$userid = bp_loggedin_user_id();
$user_avatar_url = $avatarurl = bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $userid, 'html' => false ) ); 
$user_image = '<img src="' . $user_avatar_url  . '"/>';
return $user_image;

}
add_shortcode('avatar', 'user_avatar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$userimage = "<img src='$user_avatar_url' />";`
instead

Comment: with that he would need to escape the "" inside

Comment: not sure switching between ' and " would make a difference

Comment: anyway since I'm kinda out of the options right now I tried that one too, as expected - the same thing again

Answer (score 0):

try like these

```
<?php
 function user_avatar() 
  {    
    $user_avatar_url = bp_loggedin_user_avatar( 'type=full&html=false' ); 
   $user_image = '<img src="' . $user_avatar_url  . '"/>';
   return $user_image;
 }
  add_shortcode('avatar', 'user_avatar');
?>
```